# Как получить authorization Bearer в twitter?

Tags: python, api, requests

помогите пожалуйста получить  authorization Bearer автоматически, без того, чтобы запускать браузер и оттуда через F12 его вытаскивать.
Получить гостевой токен у меня получилось для твиттера вот так

```
headers = {
        'user-agent': f'{useragent.random}',
        'authorization': f'Bearer {TOKEN}',
    
    }

    response = requests.post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/guest/activate.json', headers=headers)
    print(response.json())
```

Теперь мне нужно получить сам Bearer, чтобы не прописывать его в ручную.
Видел, что его генерирует main.js, но как получить не понимаю. Перелазил кучу форумов, но так и не нашел ответа. Help please =(
Последняя надежда

Comment: Реквест с js не работает ‍♀️

Comment: Это я понимаю, просто вдруг есть какой-либо другой способ

Comment: Другой способ - это веб драйвер (в режиме hidden) ‍♀️